# Culbera: Selecting things from dropdown list in an Android app

Tags: android, python, drop-down-menu, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to test a drop down list with Culbera. My menu structure is as follows

```
Main Page
   -- Program  - Setup - Arm    
                       - Torque 
   -- Test
```

Now `Arm`  displays (makes visible) a drop down list that shows the list of ARM types.

I want to pick one from the dropdown list and then press `Program Arm Type`. For some reason this is not working as expected.

When I used

```
python culebra -Gu -o command_trace.txt --scale=01.0
```

the trace I got is

```
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Arm').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/21").setText(u"xxx")
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'OK').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Program ArmType').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
```

It popped up a text box. (I have no idea where it is coming from)? Can someone explain how to select things from a dropdown list in Culbera

```
import re
import sys
import os
import time


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import DOWN_AND_UP

kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}

_s = 3
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

# Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
# to see if the installation worked.
#vc.installPackage('AbcApp.Android.AbcApp.Android-Signed.apk')


# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'AbcApp.Android.AbcApp.Android'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the packag
activity = 'md591ecfcc0189ae8714.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

vc.sleep(5)

def GoToView(s):
    vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(unicode(s)).touch()
    vc.sleep(_s)
    vc.dump(window=-1)

vc.dump(window=-1)

GoToView('Program')

GoToView('Setup')
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Arm').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)

vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'OK').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Program ArmType').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)


GoToView('Main')
```

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - Can you please take a look at this? Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "It popped up a text box. (I have no idea where it is coming from)?"

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - I will add the screenshots tomorrow when I reach work.  However the question of selecting a value from a dropdown list (`Bindable Picker`) still remains. Could you please explain that.?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - I don't think two are related (selecting from the dropdown list) and the text box that allows me to type in some text. It only happens in the `Tk` window when I run `Culebra`. Doesn't happen on the Android device.

Comment: Are you talking about Spinners (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - I have the screen shots now. Can I email it to you rather than post it here

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - I am using `Bindable Picker`.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - I have added screen shots :)

Comment: So it should be more or less like https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html, isn't it?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - yes. It extends Picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Picker

A **Picker** is a widget composed of other widgets such as Button and EditText.

This simple example shows a **TimePicker**

[image]

then, if you run

```
dump
```

this is part of the output

```
  android.widget.TimePicker com.dtmilano.android.demoapplication:id/timePicker 
     android.widget.NumberPicker  
        android.widget.Button  2
        android.widget.EditText android:id/numberpicker_input 3
        android.widget.Button  4
     android.widget.NumberPicker  
        android.widget.Button  33
        android.widget.EditText android:id/numberpicker_input 34
        android.widget.Button  35
     android.widget.NumberPicker  
        android.widget.EditText android:id/numberpicker_input AM
        android.widget.Button  PM
```

where you can see what I mean by *composed*.

Then, when you click on some of the **EditText**s, `culebra` understands that your intention is to enter some text and thus it shows the entry dialog

[image]

If you click on any of the **Button**s, `culebra` will also understand your intention is to increase or decrease the Picker value and generates the corresponding touches.

I'm not really sure what are the *drop down*s you mentioned. Are they **Spinner**s?
The output of `dump` will help understand.

## Spinner

The case for the **Spinner** is a bit different as it's composed of the entry and the drop down menu.

However, if you take a look at **touch zones** (CTRL+Z) you will see the entry and the drop down arrow are part of the same zone

[image]

I'm using [ApiDemos](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/ApiDemos) here so if you want to test it or ask new questions we will have something to compare.

Then, you click on the **Spinner** it opens the drop down

[image]

and you will get this code generated

```
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'green', root=vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/4')).touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'violet').touch()
```

The first `touch()` might be a little trickier if you don't know the current value then you can use either the View Id or a regular expression to match all the options.

Comment: By `dropdowns` I meant the picker that lets you choose between `SBO1`,`SBO2` and `SBO3`

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to pick a particular item from a bindable picker. Could you provide an example script in the above case?

Comment: In this case, the generated script works perfectly either entering the text you typed or clicking on the buttons to increase/decrease the value. This should be the same as your SB01, SB02... case.

Comment: Can you provide `dump` output for your scenario?